# Google Charts : change region color on click

Tags: dictionary, charts, colors, onclick, region

I'm working on a map using Google Charts.

When someone clicks on a region every region change opacity while the clicked one keeps the original color.

It's exactly like this but for regions: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#creating-material-column-charts

Do you guys know where to begin ? I can retrieve the current item selected, it's easy... but now I have to retrieve **every item** *but* the selected one and **change the color of them**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code fragment ?

Comment: Sorry Pirate X, I didn't have the time to post my link that WhiteHat did the job. Thx !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the `colorAxis` config option,
assign a higher number to the selected region
reset the remaining regions back to zero

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['England', 0],
      ['Wales', 0],
      ['Scotland', 0],
      ['Ireland', 0],
    ]);

    var options = {
      colorAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        colors: ['#FFEBEE', '#B71C1C']
      },
      region: 'GB',
      resolution: 'provinces'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        if (i === chart.getSelection()[0].row) {
          data.setValue(i, 1, 100);
        } else {
          data.setValue(i, 1, 0);
        }
      }
      chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['geochart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Dude, you know in and out of every Google Chart question. Big fan of you. Can you tell how did you learn so much ? I'm learning it but would love to have some guidance from a learned person.

Comment: thanks! here to help, i've got a lot of experience with javascript and I discovered and started using google charts a couple years ago in my job. so i've had plenty of trial and error to figure it out. plus answering questions keeps my skills sharp, and adds to my codebase. feel free to hit me up anytime you have a question...

Comment: Is there a way I can chat with you ? Little tough to have discussion over here.

Comment: chat SO is blocked at my office. Perhaps, some other day. Thanks !